# How to transform Parabola to 3D graph and lift the vertex upon a vertical line (z axis)?

Tags: analytic-geometry, quadratics, 3d, transformation

If I have a quadratic in the form of $f(x) =ax^2+bx+c$, how would I be able to transfer this onto a 3D Graph where $x$=horizontal, $y$=the other 2D dimension and $z$= height , and raise the turning point by $k$ in the $z$ axis, how might I find the equation of this 3D Graph$?$

[**Diagram (1) visualisation**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLh8y.png)
You could imagine the vertex of the green curve (the parabola), being shifted up/down the red vertical line by $k$ units, while the $x$ intercepts stay still. And then that is the new function I need the equation for.

[**Diagram (2) angle calculations**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWyKI.jpg)

In that picture, I have made the quadratic: $f(x)=-x^2+10x$, and I want to shift it up by $1$ unit in the $z$ axis. I have drawn what that new function would look like with a red pen.
I am keeping the $x$ intercepts the same, except since I am pulling the vertex upwards, the distance $AB>AC$, (look carefully at the diagram to see the letters A B and C on the graph),  so the quadratic would have stretched upwards. You could imagine that $BC$ is part of the line that I am shifting the vertex upon.

I let $k=\theta=\angle BAC$,
and draw a triangle $\triangle ABC$ onto the 3D graph, where $A$ is at the $x$ coordinate of the turning point of $f(x)$ which is $x=-b/2a=-10/-2=5$

Only the $x$ value though so I put it on the $x$ axis at $x=5\to (5,0,0)$

I make point $B$ at the turning point of my lifted curve $(x,y,z)\to(5,25,1)$
I make the point $C$ at the vertex of the original function $f(x)$ which is at $(5,25,0)$.

It is quite simple now to draw the triangle seperate from the graph. All lengths from here on are absolute and don't factor in angles.
Distance $AC$ = $25$ units, $BC$=$1$ unit, and $AB = \sqrt{AB^2+BC^2} = \sqrt{626}$ units. And by using basic trigonometry, $\theta=\angle BAC \approx 2.29°$

**How do I get my new function?**

Comment: Try the intersection between $S(x,y,z) = y-(a x^2+ b x + c)=0$ and $\Pi\to \alpha x+\beta y+\gamma z+\delta = 0$ giving $-a \beta ^2 y^2-2 a \beta  \delta  y-2 a \beta  \gamma  y z-a \delta ^2-2 a \delta  \gamma  z-a \gamma ^2 z^2-\alpha ^2 c+\alpha ^2 y+\alpha  b
   \beta  y+\alpha  b \delta +\alpha  b \gamma  z=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the equation of your curve, before transformation, is this:
$$
y = ax^2 + bx + c \\
z = 0
$$
And you'd like to transform it so that the vertex of the parabola lies at some $z$-value. Let's simplify a little, and rewrite the parabola in a vertex form:
$$
y = (x-u)^2 + w\\
z = 0
$$
which has vertex at $(u, w, 0)$. You have a bit of a problem in your goal in the case where $w = 0$, for now the vertex **is** an intercept, so "raising the vertex" and "the intercepts stay still" is a contradiction.

Let me proceed with the case where $w \ne 0$. Then the intercepts occur when $y = 0$, i.e., when 
\begin{align}
(x-u)^2 +w &= 0 \\
(x-u)^2 &= -w \\
(x-u) &= \pm\sqrt{-w} \\
x &= u \pm \sqrt{-w} 
\end{align}

So in the case where $w < 0$, this has solutions; for $w \ge 0$, your question doesn't even make sense (i.e., either the vertex is the same as the intercepts ($w = 0$) or there are no intercepts at all $(w > 0)$.

Continuing with $w < 0$, we have intercepts at 
$$
(u - \sqrt{-w}, 0, 0)\\
(u + \sqrt{-w}, 0, 0)
$$
and you'd like a "shear" operation (a linear transformation where $x$ and $y$ stay fixed, but $z$ is altered) in which these points remain fixed. So we're looking for a map
$$
(x, y, z) \mapsto (x, y, z + px + qy)
$$
where the $y = 0$ line remains fixed, so 
$$
(x, 0, z) \mapsto (x, 0, z + px) = (x, 0, z)
$$
hence $p = 0$.

And we also want to have
$$
(u, w, 0) \mapsto (u, w, H)
$$
for some target height $H$. So we need
$$
(u, w, 0) \mapsto (u, w, 0 + qw) = (u, w, H)
$$
hence $qw = H$, so $q = H/w$. Whew! Now we've got all we need. We need to transform everything by the map
$$
(x, y, z) \mapsto (x, y, z + \frac{H}{w} y)
$$
The "before" equation was
\begin{align}
y &= (x-u)^2 + w\\
z &= 0
\end{align}

The "after" equation is therefore

\begin{align}
y &= (x-u)^2 + w\\
z &= \frac{H}{w}\left((x-u)^2 + w \right)
\end{align}

Let's make this concrete with an example. Suppose we have 
$$
y = x^2 + 10x
$$
which we rewrite in vertex form as 
$$
y = (x+5)^2 - 15
$$
so that the vertex is at $(u, w) = (-5, -15)$.

We want to "lift" the vertex up three units in $z$ (I just picked $3$ arbitrarily). So our formula says to plot
\begin{align}
y &= (x+5)^2 - 15\\
z &= \frac{3}{-15}\left( (x+5)^2 - 15 \right)
\end{align}

Here's the plotted result, using geogebra:

[image]

Comment: If the equation in vertex form has a coefficient, like $a(x-u)^2+w$, would the result be be $z=(H/w)(a(x-u)^2+w)$?

Comment: Yes; the only thing used in computing the new $z$ formula was $H/w$, where $H$ is the desired height, and $(u, w)$ is the vertex. Since multiplying $(x-u)^2$ by a constant doesn't change the location of its min ($x = u$, of course), everything still works.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer to this problem.